# Team Foundation Server - Git Enabled Team Project vs Git Team Project

Tags: git, version-control, team-foundation-server

We have a TFS 2018 project, that looks like it was accidentally created as Version Control = TFVC when we wanted to use Git.  However it is git enabled; we use Git repos for Source Control.  I created a new, version control = Git, TFS Project for comparison.

Querying the REST API:

OLD:

```
 "capabilities": {
        "processTemplate": {
            "templateName": "Agile"
        },
        "versioncontrol": {
            "sourceControlType": "Tfvc",
            "gitEnabled": "True",
            "tfvcEnabled": "True"
        }
    },
```

NEW

```
 "capabilities": {
        "processTemplate": {
            "templateName": "Agile"
        },
        "versioncontrol": {
            "sourceControlType": "Git",
            "gitEnabled": "True",
            "tfvcEnabled": "False"
        }
    },
```

Can I change the old one to have the capabilities of the new one somehow?

What is the difference between a "Git Enabled" TFVC Project, and a GIT Project in TFS? If I can't just change the settings, is it worth it to move repos, work items, etc. to the new "Git only" Project? We will be upgrading to Azure DevOps Server 2019 soon if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I can`t find any problem description related to tfvc in your question.

There is no big difference between projects with default Tfvc and Git. For Tfvc project, you just get additional repository for your source control. If you don`t want to use Tfvc repository, just ignore it and use git.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I do end up with a folder on the client /OLD/$tf which is kind of weird, and I get a different landing page in TFS web, but those are the only differences I have noticed.